# Creating a ribbon effect with the border-image property

Tags: html, css-position, css

http://jsfiddle.net/94k1wuhu/

When looking at my fiddle my problem should be obvious to you. I created a border-image to create a ribbon effect (cool idea, isn't it? :D) but apparently the background-color sets the background for the border too. Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <p>Without background-color:</p>
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>With background-color:</p><br /><br />
  <h1 id="bg">Home</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #333;
}

#main {
    background-color: #efefef;
    width: 300px;
    height: 700px;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: -40px;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(http://altistest.square7.ch/templates/pscal/images/h1br.png) 20 20 20 20 stretch;
}

#bg {
    background-color: #72b743;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In browsers that support it, you can add:

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

This allows the background (colour and/or image) to extend to the border but not 'beneath' it, clipping it to the padding area. Possible values are (quoted from the link, given below):

> #### border-box
>
> > The background extends to the outside edge of the border (but underneath the border in z-ordering).
>
> #### padding-box
>
> > No background is drawn below the border (background extends to the outside edge of the padding).
>
> #### content-box
>
> > The background is painted within (clipped to) the content box.

References:

- [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped! :)